# Remove hash URLs from Google search results after removing the hash

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, url

I recently removed the hash from the URLs of my website built with AngularJS. Now I would like to remove the old URLs from the Google search results to avoid duplicate content.

Problem is, when I try to do this via the Webmaster Tools' URL removal tool, the hash gets removed from my input and Google tries to remove my root URL from the index.

Also, when I add `Disallow: /#/` to my robots.txt file, ALL requests are being blocked.

Should I just be patient and wait until Google recognizes the change or is there a way to remove these URLs?

PS: Calling the hash URLs will not lead to a 404, they are just forwarded to the non-hashed page automatically. But no hash URL is included in my sitemap nor linked anywhere on my page.

PPS: I found a similar question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72025/how-to-remove-a-fragment-hash-url-from-google-search-results), but it's not exactly the same as I didn't switch to hashbang URLs but instead I'm taking advantage of Googles relatively new ability to query AngularJS pages properly.

Comment: That other question is fundamentally the same as this. It does not need to have an accepted answer to be complete.

Comment: @John Agreed, but none of the given answers apply to my problem as they either focus on server side HTML snapshots (which I'm not using) or suggest using the Webmaster Tools or redirects (which both won't work as already commented by the OP). So I should just wait for an answer to a question that hasn't been active for a year? Ok, I'll change the title of my question to clarify the difference to the other question...

Comment: Normally adding a bounty would attract attention to the question and would almost assuredly get you the answers you are seeking. Unfortunately you do not yet have enough reputation to do that. :/

Comment: @John Exactly...